# Grails: How to mock properties for domain object with non-domain abstract base class

Tags: grails, spock

I have a grails 2.2.4 app with a domain class `Monster`:

```
class Monster {
    int aggression
}
```

I can mock and test it like so:

```
import spock.lang.*
class MonsterSpec extends Specification {
    def "property mocks work"() {
        given:
        def m = Mock(Monster)
        m.aggression >> 5

        expect:
        m.aggression == 10
    }
}
```

Recently I decided to give it an abstract base class (*not* a domain object itself) so that I could share method implementations among my many `Monster`-like classes:

```
abstract class Entity {} // Not under /domain

class RefactoredMonster extends Entity {
    int aggression
}
```

But then a thousand simple tests all broke, like so:

```
import spock.lang.*
class MonsterSpec extends Specification {
    def "property mocks work"() {
        given:
        def m = Mock(RefactoredMonster)
        m.aggression >> 10

        expect:
        m.getAggression() == 10 // This works

        and:
        m.aggression == 10 // This fails!  m.aggression is null!
    }
}
```

What on Earth is going on?  The problem goes away if I make `Entity` concrete, but then of course I can't hydrate any `Monster` objects since Hibernate doesn't know what to do with `Entity` (and I don't want to make `Entity` a domain object, though I suppose I will if I really must).

What am I missing?

Comment: can you post your stacktrace..

Comment: There isn't a stacktrace, the test just fails because `m.aggression` is null, and not `10` like it should be.  The error message is just the ordinary "Condition not satisfied" Spock failure.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is GORM expects the super class to be a domain class.

With Groovy 2.0, which is what Grails 2.2.4 has, you can use compile-time [mixins](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/10/groovy-goodness-mixin-functionality-to.html) to add methods to a class. This allows for method reuse without inheritance.

The `Entity` can remain as not a domain class, but it must be a concrete class. Then, instead of subclassing, use it as a mixin.

```
@Mixin(Entity)
class RefactoredMonster {
    int aggression
}
```

## An alternative

Since you need the ability to override methods, as you said, Mixins are out.

Looking at this from a higher level, a potential issue is the architecture/design. Inheritance is meant to represent *is-a* relationships (ex. a Dog is an Animal). But  when inheritance is used primarily as a way to reuse methods, it can lead to... a mess.

It may be better to forgo inheritance and choose *has-a* (delegation) instead. This would allow you to reuse behaviour and override it when needed. Unfortunately, Groovy 2.0 doesn't support @Delegate. So the following example is going to have more boilerplate code than the same thing coded in Groovy 2.4 would:

```
interface Flier {
    def fly();
}

class FlierImp {
    def fly() { "I'm fying! WOOT!" }
}

class RealDuck implements Flier {
    def flier

    RealDuck() {
        flier = new FlierImp() // Purposely not using injection
    }

    def fly() {
        flier.fly()
    }
}

class RubberDuck implements Flier {
    def fly() { "I don't fly" }
}

def duck = new RealDuck()
def rubberDuck = new RubberDuck()

assert duck.fly() == "I'm fying! WOOT!"
assert rubberDuck.fly() == "I don't fly"
```

In the example above `RealDuck` and `RubberDuck` represent domain classes (which is why I'm not injecting the flier). The flying behaviour is *demanded* by an interface and implemented either via a class which only implements the behaviour (`FlierImp`), or by implementing it directly, as shown in `RubberDuck`.

Comment: Are you sure it's GORM that's at fault?  Only my mocked objects are broken; my integration tests, which use real objects, all run flawlessly.  In any case, I would like `Monster` to be able to override methods in `Entity`, so Groovy's mixins aren't an option.

Comment: Well, unit tests don't use a real GORM implementation, so sometimes unexpected things happen. I don't know enough about this implementation to know how inheritance impacts it. I added an example which avoids inheritance and uses interfaces instead.